# How to make a button a menu trigger in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I tried adding an `IconButton()` and wanted to click the button to turn it **on or off** (while also **clicking elsewhere to dismiss** it)

But a funny qustion happend.

The trigger button is included in "Other Places", when I click the button to close the menu, this triggers `onDismissRequest()` first, and then triggers the button's `onClick()`, which makes me unable to close the menu (when clicked will **instantly close and then open again**)

```
Scaffold(
    ...
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            ...
            actions = {
                var menuExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

                Box {
                    IconButton(onClick = { menuExpanded = !menuExpanded}) {
                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.menu),
                            contentDescription = "menu",
                            tint = white
                        )
                    }

                    DropdownMenu(
                        expanded = menuExpanded,
                        properties = PopupProperties(),
                        onDismissRequest = { menuExpanded = false }
                    ) {
                        // items
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
) { ... }
```

I know I can set `Modifier.offset()` so that menu masks the button, but I don't want to do that.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [`PopupProperties.focusable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/window/PopupProperties#focusable()) is for: `true` value prevents other views from getting tapped while the menu is open. By the way, this is the default value if you don't specify `properties` option.

```
DropdownMenu(
    expanded = menuExpanded,
    properties = PopupProperties(focusable = true),
    onDismissRequest = { menuExpanded = false }
) {
```